# Powerpoint VBA Superscript Numbers

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've been trying to create a macro that converts all the **numbers** in a text box, on a slide, to superscript but I'm finding Powerpoint VBA to be very strange.

I've tried this short line of code as a starter, but this doesn't seem to select properly.

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select.Font.superscript = True
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: "this doesn't seem to select properly" is not a problem description. How do you invoke that code? What does it select? Why is that improper? What should happen instead? I might guess that would either (a) not select any text, only activate the slide or (b) convert everything to superscript, not just numbers, but since you already tried it, you can tell readers the outcome without us having to guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, never select anything unless you absolutely must (rare, very rare).
Next, you've selected a Slide object. Slides don't have any font properties, so you can't SET them.

Here's an example that sets all of the characters in the currently selected shape to superscript. You'll likely want to refine it to iterate through all the shapes in the slide, and to skip any characters that aren't numbers.
[Edited to Super rather than Sub-script characters and ONLY numeric characters]

```
Sub SuperscriptMe()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    For x = 1 To .Characters.Count
        ' verify that the character is a number
        If IsNumeric(.Characters(x)) then
           .Characters(x).Font.Superscript = True
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```